# Disabling JVM caching impact - Jetty

Tags: caching, jvm, jetty, jetty-9

JVM built-in URL caching causes an intermittent issue with Jetty while accessing the added jars.

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:669) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:309) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1005) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:569) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:567) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:566) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
```

This can be resolved if the JVM caches are disabled by adding the following XML snippet to the corresponding Jetty configuration (jetty.xml) file.

```
<Set class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource" name="defaultUseCaches">false</Set>
```

What is the impact on an application performance if we disable the JVM caches with Jetty?

Comment: have you tried measuring the impact on your specific application?

Comment: No not yet. What can be a possible impact on the application performance if the JVM caches are disabled with Jetty ?